# Variable type detection in python

Tags: python, typechecking, duck-typing, runtime-type

I am looking at methods for detecting the type of a variable (list vs string) within python (2.5+), and came across some other answers which seemed overly convoluted.

I have found one can do

```
x.__class__.__name__
```

to get a string containing the class name. What, if anything, is wrong with this? Is it not portable? When would it fail?

Comment: AFAIK it's fine, but what's wrong with using `isinstance()`?

Comment: What about `type()` method ?

Comment: @doublep Absolutely nothing -- this just highlights my miscomprehension :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that different classes can have the same name.

The straightforward example is for classes defined in different modules (e.g. think of generic common names such as `Node` or `Connection`).

However, it's easy to demonstrate this problem even in a single module:

```
class A(object): pass
B = A
class A(object): pass
C = A

b = B()
c = C()
b.__class__.__name__ == c.__class__.__name__
=> True
type(b) == type(c)
=> False
```

If you don't have to have string-representation of the class, simply use the `type` object returned by calling `type(obj)`.

Of course, depending on what you use it for, it might be best to use `isinstance` instead of dealing with `type` objects directly.

Comment: Thanks, type objects were a partial source of confusion for me here.

Answer (score 3):

It'll fail for old-style classes; `isinstance()` works just fine:

```
>>> class OldStyle: pass
...
>>> OldStyle.__class__.__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: class OldStyle has no attribute '__class__'
>>> isinstance(OldStyle(), OldStyle)
True
```

Note that it is better to use `isinstance()` and accept subclasses, including *virtual* subclasses (via [abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-abstract-base-class)). Don't tie your code to a specific type.

For example, you'd not want to test for `obj.__class__.__name__ in ('int', 'float', 'complex')` when you could just use `isinstance(obj, numbers.Number)`; that way your code will accept `decimal.Decimal` objects too.

Answer (score 1):

One common pitfails for detecting strings in Python 2.x would be mixing up `str` and `unicode` types.

```
assert isinstance("", str) is True
assert isinstance(u"", str) is True  # AssertionError!
assert isinstance(u"", unicode) is True
assert isinstance(u"", unicode) is True
assert isinstance("", unicode) is True  # AssertionError!
# Both lines below are always correct
assert isinstance("", basestring) is True
assert isinstance(u"", basestring) is True
```

As you can see, all string derives from same base class - that's what allow uniform type check. It won't be possible with class name string look up.

```
>>> "".__class__.__name__
'str'
>>> u"".__class__.__name__
'unicode'
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re not really supposed to call *magic* functions, you could just use `type()` or `isinstance()`. The main difference between the two is that `isinstance()` supports inheritance, so if your classes inherit from other classes you might wanna use `isinstance()`.